Generate and validate LocalTime from OpenAPI specification YAML
I was able to make OpenAPI Generator for Gradle make fields with the LocalTime data type using the following answer:
Generate `LocalTime` from OpenAPI specification
Works great, until I want to add the required: section in the YAML definition for the newly created field.
When I send a value, I get the following error:
o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod: 
Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.sample.SampleResponse> 
com.sample.SampleController.doCreate(com.sample.SampleRequest,org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken) 
throws java.lang.Exception: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'java.time.LocalTime'

When checking the generated class, I can see that it is annotated this way:
  @NotBlank@Valid 
  @Schema(name = "sampleTime", example = "12:34:56", description = "sample time", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)

I'm not too sure where to begin here to change the @NotBlank annotation for data types defined through the format specification in OpenAPI, but since this is a LocalTime type, it doesnt seem like I can use pattern to check for empty strings sent in the JSON while setting the Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED value.
So I guess what I want to ask is, how do I define constraints that can be autogenerated for non-standard OpenAPI types using the YAML file?
